# How to use <jt:span /> tag with nested <jt:forEach></jt:forEach>?

Tags: jett

I got parse error exception when I try to use  with nested .
Can Span tag use along with nested loop?

[image]

```
     Subunit                                                 |                                                    Fiber                                              |   IL   |    RL    | XX |    RL
-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+----+-----------------------------------
<jt:span factor="${wo.serialNumbers.size}" value="${wo.id}"/>|<jt:forEach items="${workOrders}" var="wo"><jt:forEach items="${wo.serialNumbers}" var="sn">${sn.fiber}|${sn.il}|${sn.rl_a}| XX |${sn.rl_b}</jt:forEach><jt:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a `jt:span` tag can be used along side a `jt:forEach`, even if it's nested.  The error you're getting is most likely because you're referencing the variable `wo` in the `jt:span` tag on the left from outside of the `jt:forEach` loop it's defined in, which is the cells to the right.

If you plan to have multiple `span` tags, one for each work order, then include it in the body of the outer `jt:forEach` tag.  Move the outer `jt:forEach` tag to the beginning of the leftmost cell.

```
                Subunit                                                                                 |                        Fiber                               |   IL   |    RL    | XX |    RL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+----+-----------------------------------
<jt:forEach items="${workOrders}" var="wo"><jt:span factor="${wo.serialNumbers.size}" value="${wo.id}"/>|<jt:forEach items="${wo.serialNumbers}" var="sn">${sn.fiber}|${sn.il}|${sn.rl_a}| XX |${sn.rl_b}</jt:forEach><jt:forEach>
```

This will make `wo` be in scope in the outer `jt:forEach` tag and produce the `span`s for the inner `jt:forEach` tags.